# Why is a confidence ellipse based on multivariate-t tighter than one base on multivariate norm (R)

Tags: confidence-interval, ggplot2, ellipse

I want to draw a 95% confidence ellipse around my bivariate data. Using `ggplot2::stat_ellipse()` with `type="t"` (for a bivariate-t distribution) the confidence region is tighter than for `type="norm"`.  This is counter-intuitive, and there is very little description of the methods used in both `ggplot2::stat_ellipse()` or `car::confidenceEllipse()` (on which the ggplot2 command is based).
Any explanations as to why this result shows up this way are greatly appreciated.  Ideally, I would want the ellipse based on the t-distribution because of a small sample size (n=15), but I want to be confident that I know what it's doing.

```
# Some simulated correlated data:
foo.x <- rnorm(15, mean=10, sd=5)  
foo.err <- rnorm(15, mean=0, sd=1)  
foo.df <- data.frame(x=foo.x, y=foo.x+foo.err)

# plot data with confidence ellipses
ggplot(data=foo.df, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point(size=2) +  
  stat_ellipse(type = "norm", lty=1, col=1) +  
  stat_ellipse(type = "t", lty=2, col=2)
```

[image: confidence ellipses]
In this plot, the red dashed line is the ellipse based on the t-distribution, and the solid black line the ellipse based on the normal.  (Sorry there is no legend on the plot to show what the line types represent; I tried to make that happen, but gave up before finding success.)

Comment: These don't look like confidence ellipses--at least not for the means.  They're far too big.  They look more like what might be called "data ellipses."